# defining python classes that take multiple keyword arguments

Tags: python

I need to define a class that will take multiple keyword parameters.

My code looks like this:

```
class test1:
    def __init__(self,parm1=val1, parm2=val2):
        self.x = parm1
        self.y = parm2
        print('parm1',self.x)


def main():
    x = test1(1,2)
```

but I get an error that `val1` is not defined. What would be the proper way ?

Comment: What is `val1` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `val1` and `val2` *before* you define your class `test`:

```
val1 = 1
val2 = 3.141592653

class test(object):
    def __init__(self, param1=val1, param2=val2):
        self.x = param1
        self.y = param2
```

This approach can have its advantages (say, if `val1` and `val2` should be some generic default values read from the environment...), but is not really readable. It'd be best to use something like:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, param1=None, param2=None):
        if param1 is None:
            self.x = val1
        else: 
            self.x = val2
```

where once again, `val1` and `val2` are defined *before* the definition of `test`...

Answer (score 2):

```
def __init__(self,parm1=None,parm2=None):...
```

not sure what you are doing with the val1 and val2 ... the error is telling you that those variables dont exist ... so you cannot use them... so make them exist or do something else...

Answer (score 1):

Make val1 and val2 a string. As variables they are not defined. If they are just placeholders use None as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Function argument default values must exist when the function is `def`ined because a copy of their value is stored as part of the function's compiled code at that time, not later every time the function is called. Typically, `None` is used as the default value in the declaration and then detected in the function's body where it is replaced with the real (possibly dynamically-computed) default value.